# How to create a dynamic UML-diagram from HTML Tables?

Tags: html, css, api, uml

### EDIT 1:

How about if I make them into a class and turn that into a UML-diagram that way?

---

I would like to create a dynamic UML-diagram based off my HTML code if that is possible.

The code looks like this:

```
<h2><a id="Foo"><br />Foo</a></h2>
<h3><a id="FooHead"><br />FooHead</a></h3>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Field</th>
        <th>Datatype</th>
        <th>Length</th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo1</td>
        <td>String</td>
        <td>32</td>
        <td>M</td>
        <td>Unique foo number.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo2</td>
        <td>String</td>
        <td>32</td>
        <td>M</td>
        <td>Foo2.</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<h3><a id="FooLine"><br />FooLine</a></h3>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Field</th>
        <th>Datatype</th>
        <th>Length</th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo1</td>
        <td>String</td>
        <td>32</td>
        <td>M</td>
        <td>Unique foo number.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo6</td>
        <td>String</td>
        <td>32</td>
        <td>M</td>
        <td>Foo6.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo7</td>
        <td>String</td>
        <td>32</td>
        <td>M</td>
        <td>Foo7.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The UML-diagram should look something like this (see below). I have tried googling around and couldn't really find anything. Any ideas for solutions or anything pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

[image: UML-Diagram]

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @ThomasKilian I tried googling similar problems / solutions. "XML-Diagram from HMTL" and the likes of this. Couldn't find anything.

Comment: But SO is no Google extension. You need to make an attempt beyond Google (that is using your brain and creativity).

Comment: @ThomasKilian You aren't very helpful. I'm looking for guidance on where to even start looking or if anyone has had a similar problem. I don't want to reinvent the wheel if it's not needed.

Comment: Please read here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question

Answer (score 2):

In order to style tables into UML classifiers (classes, interfaces, etc.), [CSS](https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/) might be useful. [CSS selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html%23id-selectors) might help you to style specific columns for specific informations (name, type, or non-standard informations such as the length).

If you want do draw relationships between your tables, the simple solution is to use some Javascript library such as [JSPlumb](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/demo/flowchart/index.html) or  [Raphael](http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/).

Finally, if you want to leave the HTML tables, here is some advertising for a personal work with [Polymer Web components](https://www.polymer-project.org) . [Polymeria UML](http://bdulac.github.io/polymeria/introduction/) is a set of [web components](http://webcomponents.org). Inspired by Eclipse UML2 elements, it supports generic class diagram elements. This is a work in progress: the current version is based on Polymer 0.5. An evolution for Polymer 1.0 might be available soon.

Comment: I'll look into this!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

[image]

Here is the complete implementation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>UML Class Nodes</title>
<meta name="description" content="UML Class-like nodes showing two collapsible lists of items." />
<!-- Copyright 1998-2016 by Northwoods Software Corporation. -->
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="go.js"></script>
<link href="../assets/css/goSamples.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  <!-- you don't need to use this -->
<script src="goSamples.js"></script>  <!-- this is only for the GoJS Samples framework -->
<script id="code">
  function init() {
    if (window.goSamples) goSamples();  // init for these samples -- you don't need to call this
    var $ = go.GraphObject.make;

    myDiagram =
      $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv",
        {
          initialContentAlignment: go.Spot.Center,
          isReadOnly: true
        });

    // show visibility or access as a single character at the beginning of each property or method
    function convertVisibility(v) {
      switch (v) {
        case "public": return "+";
        case "private": return "-";
        case "protected": return "#";
        case "package": return "~";
        default: return v;
      }
    }

    // the item template for properties
    var propertyTemplate =
      $(go.Panel, "Horizontal",
        // property visibility/access
        $(go.TextBlock, "-",
          { isMultiline: false, editable: false, width: 12 },
          new go.Binding("text", "visibility", convertVisibility)),
        // property name, underlined if scope=="class" to indicate static property
        $(go.TextBlock,
          { isMultiline: false, editable: true },
          new go.Binding("text", "name").makeTwoWay(),
          new go.Binding("isUnderline", "scope", function(s) { return s[0] === 'c' })),
        // property type, if known
        $(go.TextBlock, "",
          new go.Binding("text", "type", function(t) { return (t ? ": " : ""); })),
        $(go.TextBlock,
          { isMultiline: false, editable: true },
          new go.Binding("text", "type").makeTwoWay()),
        // property default value, if any
        $(go.TextBlock,
          { isMultiline: false, editable: false },
          new go.Binding("text", "default", function(s) { return s ? " = " + s : ""; }))
      );

    // this simple template does not have any buttons to permit adding or
    // removing properties or methods, but it could!
    myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
      $(go.Node, "Auto",
        {
          locationSpot: go.Spot.Center,
          fromSpot: go.Spot.AllSides,
          toSpot: go.Spot.AllSides
        },
        $(go.Shape, { fill: "lightyellow" }),
        $(go.Panel, "Table",
          { defaultRowSeparatorStroke: "black" },
          // header
          $(go.TextBlock,
            {
              row: 0, columnSpan: 2, margin: 3, alignment: go.Spot.Center,
              font: "bold 12pt sans-serif",
              isMultiline: false, editable: true
            },
            new go.Binding("text", "name").makeTwoWay()),
          // properties
          $(go.Panel, "Vertical", { name: "PROPERTIES" },
            new go.Binding("itemArray", "properties"),
            {
              row: 1, margin: 3, stretch: go.GraphObject.Fill,
              defaultAlignment: go.Spot.Left, background: "lightyellow",
              itemTemplate: propertyTemplate
            }
          )
        )
      );

    function convertIsTreeLink(r) {
      return r === "generalization";
    }

    function convertFromArrow(r) {
      switch (r) {
        case "generalization": return "";
        default: return "";
      }
    }

    function convertToArrow(r) {
      switch (r) {
        case "generalization": return "Triangle";
        case "aggregation": return "StretchedDiamond";
        default: return "";
      }
    }

    myDiagram.linkTemplate =
      $(go.Link,
        { routing: go.Link.Orthogonal },
        new go.Binding("isLayoutPositioned", "relationship", convertIsTreeLink),
        $(go.Shape),
        $(go.Shape, { scale: 1.3, fill: "white" },
          new go.Binding("fromArrow", "relationship", convertFromArrow)),
        $(go.Shape, { scale: 1.3, fill: "white" },
          new go.Binding("toArrow", "relationship", convertToArrow))
      );

    var nodeDataArray = [];
    var headers = document.querySelectorAll("h3 a[id]");
    for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
      var head = headers.item(i);
      nodeDataArray.push({
        key: head.id,
        name: head.id
      });
    }
    var tables = document.querySelectorAll("table");
    for (var j = 0; j < tables.length; j++) {
      var tab = tables.item(j);
      var arr = [];
      var rows = tab.querySelectorAll("tr");
      for (var k = 0; k < rows.length; k++) {
        if (k === 0) continue;
        var row = rows.item(k);
        var cells = row.querySelectorAll("td");
        arr.push({
          name: cells.item(0).innerText,
          type: cells.item(1).innerText
        });
      }
      nodeDataArray[j].properties = arr;
    }

    var linkDataArray = [];
    //??? how to determine relationships from HTML tables

    myDiagram.model = $(go.GraphLinksModel,
      {
        copiesArrays: true,
        copiesArrayObjects: true,
        nodeDataArray: nodeDataArray,
        linkDataArray: linkDataArray
      });
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
<div id="sample">
  <div id="myDiagramDiv" style="border: solid 1px black; width:100%; height:300px"></div>
  This sample is adapted and simplified from <a href="https://gojs.net/latest/samples/umlClass.html">GoJS UML Class sample</a>.
  Data is taken from these HTML tables:
  <h2><a id="Foo"><br />Foo</a></h2>
  <h3><a id="FooHead"><br />FooHead</a></h3>
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>Field</th>
      <th>Datatype</th>
      <th>Length</th>
      <th></th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Foo1</td>
      <td>String</td>
      <td>32</td>
      <td>M</td>
      <td>Unique foo number.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Foo2</td>
      <td>String</td>
      <td>32</td>
      <td>M</td>
      <td>Foo2.</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <h3><a id="FooLine"><br />FooLine</a></h3>
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>Field</th>
      <th>Datatype</th>
      <th>Length</th>
      <th></th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Foo1</td>
      <td>String</td>
      <td>32</td>
      <td>M</td>
      <td>Unique foo number.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Foo6</td>
      <td>String</td>
      <td>32</td>
      <td>M</td>
      <td>Foo6.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Foo7</td>
      <td>String</td>
      <td>32</td>
      <td>M</td>
      <td>Foo7.</td>
    </tr>
  </table></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The code was adapted from the [GoJS](http://gojs.net) sample: [UML Class](http://gojs.net/latest/samples/umlClass.html)

Comment: I have inlined the temporary HTML page that had held the example code until recently.